# Coroutines with Subroutines in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, async-await, yield, coroutine

Visual Studio 2015 supports coroutines, so I can do this, for example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<experimental/generator> 

auto gen(int increment) {
  int i=1;
  while(true) {
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) yield j;
    i+=increment;
  }
}


int main()
{
  auto Coroutine1=gen(1);
  auto Coroutine2=gen(2);
  auto Iterator1=Coroutine1.begin();
  auto Iterator2=Coroutine2.begin();
  for(int k=0; k<10; k++) {
    std::cout<<(*Iterator1)<<" "<<(*Iterator2)<<endl;
    ++Iterator1;
    ++Iterator2;
  }
```

which produces this output:

```
0 0
0 0
1 1
0 2
1 0
2 1
0 2
1 3
2 4
3 0
```

This is a somewhat contrived example, just to show a case which cannot be trivially implemented without coroutines.

Now, my question: How can I put "yield" into a subroutine? The following code does not compile, but ideally, I want something like this:

```
auto genSubroutine(int current){
  for(int j=0; j<current; j++) yield j;
}

auto gen(int increment) {
  int i=1;
  while(true) {
    genSubroutine(i);
    i+=increment;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use yield again: for (auto j: genSubroutine(i)) yield j;

Comment: They are stackless coroutines (vs stackful) so you can't natively yield from anywhere else than the coroutine function itself.